# Checking for a delayed effect

Tags: time-series, correlation, lags

I am examining the relationship between rides on a subway and temperature. How can one calculate a correlation with a delay?

For example, I want to see if rides increase after an increase in temperature the day before.

Answer (score 0):

There is an cross-correlation analysis based on moment of methods estimators of covariance structure.

One thing to note with this is that you might have to remove some linear structure first before making this analysis, for example strong seasonality in one or both of the series can mask this temporal dependency. Prewhitening is method to handle this:

https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat510/node/75/

Comment: Here is an link to my earlier problem with this method:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24996450/problem-when-doing-pre-whitening-before-ccf-analysis